# Cannot install dvdcli on my CentOS 7 host

Tags: docker, mesos

I tried to install dvdcli on my mesos master.

I typed the following line in the console. But I get forbidden error.

I even tried to do a direct download. Still I get forbidden error.

curl -sSL https://dl.bintray.com/emccode/dvdcli/install | sh -s stable

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Its not just you https://github.com/rexray/dvdcli/issues/37. That was posted back in June and its still unresolved.

Also Dell is no longer funding the open source Code Team initiative https://blog.thecodeteam.com/2018/02/22/final-thank-code-team/ so I'm not sure about the future of the project. I have not been following it closely. I would suggest reaching out to on  https://github.com/rexray/dvdcli/issues/37. Hopefully someone will have an answer for you there